# Adding git-prompt to my Bash profile clobbered my Bash prompt pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv version indicator. How to restore pyenv to prompt?

Tags: git, prompt, bash, pyenv

When I setup [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) + [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv), they seemed to auto-magically add the current python version name or pyvenv/virtualenv name to the command prompt. great, very useful.

```
if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init -)"; fi
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
```

I added [git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) and [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) to my ~/.bash_profile with

```
# Enable tab completion
source ~/.git-completion.bash

# colors!
red="\[\033[1;31,\]"
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
blue="\[\033[0;34m\]"
purple="\[\033[0;35m\]"
cyan="\[\033[1;36m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

# Change command prompt
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u $cyan>>>$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W \$ $reset"
```

Regardless of the order, the pyenv is not included in the prompt. I had been hoping pyenv was just tacking onto whatever the prompt string was set to such that including it after the git stuff would allow it to insert itself.

I have tried include the pyenv code above the git stuff and then capture the `$pyenv local` output and add it as a variable but my Bash skills are wanting. I went hunting in the pyenv code for the shell prompt export code but again, Bash skills are wanting.

Is there a right way to recapture/insert the pyenv version back into the prompt?

I am was attempting to get something along the lines of:

```
\u(username) >>> (pyenv/py(venv)-version) | (__git_ps1) | \w(pwd) \$
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Just stick `$(pyenv version-name)` into the appropriate place in your `$PS1`.  Something like:

```
export PS1="\u >>> $(pyenv version-name) $(__git_ps1) \w\$ "
```

(Add back your colours, as desired.)