# Enable pyenv-virtualenv prompt at terminal

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I just installed pyenv and virtualenv following:
https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

After completing installation I was prompted with:

```
pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior
```

I added `export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1` to my `.bash_aliases` just to see what the behavior would be, and sure enough it removed the prompt that used to exist at the beginning of the command prompt indicating the pyenv-virtualenv version. Used to be like:

`(myenv) user@foo:~/my_project [main] $`

where `(myenv)` is the active environment, and `[main]` is the git branch.

I would love to have the environment indicator back! It is very useful. I guess at some possibilities such as:

`export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=0`

`export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_ENABLE_PROMPT=1`

But these do not return the previous behavior. I have googled all over and can't figure out how to get this back.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123927/adding-git-prompt-to-my-bash-profile-clobbered-my-bash-prompt-pyenv-pyenv-virtua) is not useful, as it seems like a hack around the original functionality, and displays the environment always, not just when I enter (or manually activate) an environment.

Comment: The previous behaviour is [going to be removed](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/135), so in the future, you'll need to add it to your shell configuration yourself. There is [an example](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/135#issuecomment-168395839) on that issue.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Since that solution was from 2016, I scrolled down on that GH issue and found another simpler solution from 2021 (that also preserves my existing prompt custom colors and git branch indicator). I will post that below as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrowing a solution from [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/135#issuecomment-951074873), the following works (added to `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`):

```
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
export BASE_PROMPT=$PS1
function updatePrompt {
    if [[ "$(pyenv virtualenvs)" == *"* $(pyenv version-name) "* ]]; then
        export PS1='($(pyenv version-name)) '$BASE_PROMPT
    else
        export PS1=$BASE_PROMPT
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='updatePrompt'
```